# Fill the cell based on 'IF' Condition by using Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I want to use Excel function to fill the empty cells with "x" as shown in the Image. I tried using "IF" Statement to compare and return the value but I am not successful in doing so.

Please help me to correct the formula I have used 
 "**=IF(AND(C$4>=$A5;C$4<=$B5);"x";"")**"

Excel Table: [image: Excel table]

Required Output: [image: Output filled with x]

Comment: It works on my sheet. Are the cells C4 A5 and B5 text or really numbers formatted as dates?

Comment: It is used as text but any other proposals I can also try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your issue might lie in the format as text. 
In order to reach the expected result, you need to extract the number out of your different cells
For `C$4` you need `=Mid(C4;4;Find("/";C4;1)-4)` this will return **1** and will work for any Calender week.

So your formula:

```
=IF(AND(C$4>=$A5;C$4<=$B5);"x";"")
```

becomes:

```
=IF(AND(Mid(C$4;4;Find("/";C$4;1)-4)>=Mid($A5;4;Find("/";$A5;1)-4);Mid(C$4;4;Find("/";C$4;1)-4)<=Mid($B5;4;Find("/";$B5;1)-4));"x";"")
```

This formula will not see the difference between the different years though (so you cannot change the years on your sheet in the **CW 1/2019**

Comment: With the proposed formula I am only able to fill CW 1/2019 and CW 11/2019 cells as "x" remaining are just blank

Comment: Is the same will be possible by VBA ?

Comment: You mean it only works in the first line and the lines after for ex.  "CW 3/2019 and CW 13/2019" remain blanks?

Comment: Yes it remains blank only first row is filled with "x"

Comment: it came from the dollar sign ($) in the formula. If you use my formula now it should be adjusted. Otherwise just click on the formula bar to check which cells are taken in your formula